# Highlighting in MvC 5 using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to compare two values in a view to see if they are equal or not, if they are equal then don't highlight if they are NOT equal then highlight the new value. Everything I'm trying isn't working could anyone example what I'm doing wrong please?

```
<div>
     Old Registered Host Name:
     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OldHostName, new { htmlAttributes = new {@id = "oldhostname"}})
</div>
<div>
     Registered Host Name:
     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NewHostName, new { htmlAttributes = new {@id = "newhostname"}})
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
     if(document.getElementById('oldhostname').value != document.getElementById('newhostname').value)
      { 
        document.getElementById('newhostname').style.backgroundColor = "#FDFF47";
      }
});
</script>
```

Comment: `@Html.DisplayFor()` does not generate a html element - just text (and your `new { htmlAttributes... }` is pointless and does nothing (look at the html your generating) - you do not have any element with `id="oldhostname"` or `id="newhostname"`

Comment: ummm great so because @Html.DisplayFor() does not generate a html element I am unable to use it in the way I desire. when I do inspect element there is no element ID like there is for @Html.EditorFor. Have any other suggestions for a different route?

Comment: What is the point of this (why are you not handling it when editing the values)? - but the answer by Dymos shows one solution)

Comment: Because someone needs to review the changes and approve the changes, which the individual wants to see whats already in the database and whats being changed. If the two values are different they want the changed value to be highlighted, I do not want the individual who is reviewing to be able to change the data. The host name is just one item being display I have about 20 other items that i need to show the old value in the database and the new value being changed. Having the changed values highlighted makes it easier for the reviewer

Comment: You do not need javascript for that - you can just apply a class name when generating the view from the server

Comment: Okay, I don't know if this is correct or not but it works. btw my experience level is a college intern creating a website so your feed back is very appreciated.  I created a class with all my variables and a set of Boolean variables to set to true or false in my controller depending if the two variables are equal or not then in my view I'm just simply doing a if (true) else statements in the view for highlighting.

Comment: That's one way, or have a `string ClassName` property in your view model and set its value depending on the equality of `OldHostName` and `NewHostName` and then `<span class=@Model.ClassName>@Model.NewHostName</span>` (lots of ways it can be done)

Answer (score 0):

My C#/cshtml is a bit rusty, but it looks like this would render just a few divs with some text content. To get what you need you need to either

- render an element with an ID that has the text content that you want to check
- render an input with an ID that has the value that you want to check

Your JS uses HTMLElement.value which is not valid for just any element a `div` for example does not have a `value`

If your resulting HTML would look similar to:

```
<div> Old host name: <span id="oldhostname">...</span> </div>
<div> New host name: <span id="newhostname">...</span> </div>
```

Then you could check values in JS with

```
var old = document.getElementById('oldhostname').textContent;
var new = document.getElementById('newhostname').textContent;
if (old !== new) {
    console.log('different!');
}
```